# Limits of the p-norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ with $1 \leq f \leq 2$ set $$N(p)=\left( \int_0^1 f^p dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \qquad p \neq 0$$
To find the three limits $\lim_{p\rightarrow \pm \infty} N(p)$ and $\lim_{p\rightarrow 0} N(p)$.

$\\$

One thing is clear: $\liminf_{p\rightarrow \infty} N(p) \geq 1$.

Comment: $\liminf_{p\rightarrow 0^{+}} N(p) \neq + \infty$

Comment: right, sorry let me edit that part...

Comment: Aren't the hints in Rudin enough?  Look at the exercises in chapter 3 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: If  $f$  is any continuous real function then    $\lim_{p \to +  \infty } (\int_0^1| f(x)|^p dx )^{1/p} = \max \{ |f(x)| :  0 \leq x \leq 1\}.$

Answer (score 1):

For $p>0$
$$
1\leqslant N(p)=\left( \int_0^1 f^p dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leqslant (2^p)^{1/p}=2
$$
For $p<0$, let $q=-p$. 
$$
1\leqslant N(p)=N(-q)=\frac1{\left( \int_0^1 \frac1{f^q} dx \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}} \leqslant 2
$$
Since 
$$
\liminf_{p\to0^+}N(p)\geqslant 1\quad\text{and }\quad\limsup_{p\to0^-}N(p)\leqslant 1
$$
We have 
$$
\liminf_{p\to0}N(p)=\limsup_{p\to0}N(p)=1\quad\text{or }\quad\lim_{p\to0}N(p)=1
$$
Moreover we have
$$
\liminf_{p\to{\pm\infty}}N(p)=1 \quad\text{and }\quad\limsup_{p\to{\pm\infty}}N(p)=2
$$
It is easy to find particular $f$ to attain above limits.

If $f$ is continuous, then 
$$
\lim_{p\to{\pm\infty}}N(p)=\sup{\{f(x):x\in[0,1]\}}=2
$$